# SAS - Split single column into two based value of non-binary ID column

Tags: sas

I have data which is as follows:

```
data have;
  length
    group       8
    replicate   $ 1
    day         8
    observation 8
  ;
  input (_all_) (:);
datalines;
1 A 1 0
1 A 1 5
1 A 1 3
1 A 1 3
1 A 2 7
1 A 2 2
1 A 2 4
1 A 2 2
1 B 1 1
1 B 1 3
1 B 1 8
1 B 1 0
1 B 2 3
1 B 2 8
1 B 2 1
1 B 2 3
1 C 1 1
1 C 1 5
1 C 1 2
1 C 1 7
1 C 2 2
1 C 2 1
1 C 2 4
1 C 2 1
2 A 1 7
2 A 1 5
2 A 1 3
2 A 1 1
2 A 2 0
2 A 2 5
2 A 2 3
2 A 2 0
2 B 1 0
2 B 1 3
2 B 1 4
2 B 1 8
2 B 2 1
2 B 2 3
2 B 2 4
2 B 2 0
2 C 1 0
2 C 1 4
2 C 1 3
2 C 1 1
2 C 2 2
2 C 2 3
2 C 2 0
2 C 2 1
3 A 1 4
3 A 1 5
3 A 1 6
3 A 1 7
3 A 2 3
3 A 2 1
3 A 2 5
3 A 2 2
3 B 1 2
3 B 1 0
3 B 1 2
3 B 1 3
3 B 2 0
3 B 2 6
3 B 2 3
3 B 2 7
3 C 1 7
3 C 1 5
3 C 1 3
3 C 1 1
3 C 2 0
3 C 2 3
3 C 2 2
3 C 2 1
;
run;
```

I want to split `observation` into two columns based on `day`.

```
                                        observation_    observation_
           Obs    group    replicate        day_1           day_2

             1      1          A              0               7
             2      1          A              5               2
             3      1          A              3               4
             4      1          A              3               2
             5      1          B              1               3
             6      1          B              3               8
             7      1          B              8               1
             8      1          B              0               3
             9      1          C              1               2
            10      1          C              5               1
            11      1          C              2               4
            12      1          C              7               1
            13      2          A              7               0
            14      2          A              5               5
            15      2          A              3               3
            16      2          A              1               0
            17      2          B              0               1
            18      2          B              3               3
            19      2          B              4               4
            20      2          B              8               0
            21      2          C              0               2
            22      2          C              4               3
            23      2          C              3               0
            24      2          C              1               1
            25      3          A              4               3
            26      3          A              5               1
            27      3          A              6               5
            28      3          A              7               2
            29      3          B              2               0
            30      3          B              0               6
            31      3          B              2               3
            32      3          B              3               7
            33      3          C              7               0
            34      3          C              5               3
            35      3          C              3               2
            36      3          C              1               1
```

The observant SO reader will notice that I have asked essentially the same question [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077338/sas-split-single-column-into-two-based-on-value-of-an-id-column).  However, because of SAS's obsession with "levels" and "by groups", since the variable being used to split the variable of interest isn't binary, that solution doesn't generalize.

Trying it directly, the following occurs:

```
proc sort data = have out = sorted;
  by
    group
    replicate
  ;
run;

proc transpose data = sorted out = test;
  by
    group
    replicate
  ;
  var observation;
  id day;
run;
```

> ERROR: The ID value "_1" occurs twice in the same BY group.

I can use a [LET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033305/proc-transpose-with-duplicate-id-values) statement to repress the errors, but in addition to cluttering up the log, SAS retains only the last observation of each BY group.

```
proc sort data = have out = sorted;
  by
    group
    replicate
  ;
run;

proc transpose data = sorted out = test let;
  by
    group
    replicate
  ;
  var observation;
  id day;
run;

              Obs    group    replicate      _NAME_       _1    _2

               1       1          A        observation     3     2
               2       1          B        observation     0     3
               3       1          C        observation     7     1
               4       2          A        observation     1     0
               5       2          B        observation     8     0
               6       2          C        observation     1     1
               7       3          A        observation     7     2
               8       3          B        observation     3     7
               9       3          C        observation     1     1
```

I don't doubt there's some kludgy way it could be done, such as splitting each group into a separate data set and then re-merging them.  It seems like it should be doable with PROC TRANSPOSE, although how escapes me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're talking about with "SAS's obsession...", but the issue here is fairly straightforward; you need to tell SAS  about the four rows (or whatever) being separate, distinct rows.  `by` tells SAS what the row-level ID is, but you're lying to it when you say `by group replicate`, since there are still multiple rows under that.  So you need to have a unique key.  (This would be true in any database-like language, nothing unique to SAS here.  )

I would do this - make a `day_row` field, then sort by that.

```
data have_id;
  set have;
  by group replicate day;
  if first.day then day_row = 0;
  day_row+1;
run;

proc sort data=have_id;
  by group replicate day_row;
run;
proc transpose data=have_id out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=observation_day_;
  by group replicate day_row;
  var observation;
  id day;
run;
```

Comment: I suppose the part that always confuses me is that, in some situations, BY or CLASS statements behave as or similarly to, primary keys.  As always, your replies are illuminating and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your output looks like you don't want to transpose the data but instead just want split it into DAY1 and DAY2 sets and merge them back together.  This will just pair the multiple readings per BY group in the same order that they appear, which is what it looks like you did in your example.

```
data want ;
  merge
    have(where=(day=1) rename=(observation=day_1))
    have(where=(day=2) rename=(observation=day_2))
  ;
  by group replicate;
  drop day ;
run;
```

You can read the source data as many times as you need for the number of values of DAY.

If you think that you might not have the same number of observations per BY group for each DAY then you should add these statements at the end of the data step.

```
output;
call missing(of day_:);
```